# Having static design template on dynamic php pages

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a web application in PHP and I have designed my initial `index.php` with a login page with other header and footer design.

I want to keep the header and footer design throughout the pages and just want to change the included `.php`file as per the user redirection.

Please see the snippets below.
P.S. it is not complete code and it is work in progress.

```
session_start();
ob_start();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: private');

require_once ('lib/php/connection.php');
require_once ('lib/php/global.php');
require_once ('lib/php/session.php');
require_once ('lib/php/function.php');

$aController = array_values( array_diff( explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));

if (isset($aController[0])) {

    switch (strtolower($aController[0])) {

        /*case 'login';
            $setPage = 'dir_login/index.php';
            $setTitle = 'Login';
            break;*/
        case 'forgot-password';
            $setPage = 'dir_content/forgotPassword.php';
            $setTitle = 'Forgot your password';
            break;
        default:
            $setPage = 'dir_content/error.php';
            $setTitle = '404 Error';
            break;
    }
} else {
        //for all the default cases
        $setPage = 'dir_login/index.php';
        $setTitle = 'Login';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<?php
    echo '<title>';
    if (isset($setTitle)) {
        echo $setTitle;
        echo ' - ';
    }
    echo D_COMPANY_NAME;
    echo '</title>';
    if (defined ('D_PROJECT_TITLE')) {
        echo '<meta name="project-title" lang="en" content="'.htmlspecialchars(D_PROJECT_TITLE, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';
    }
    if (defined ('D_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION')) {
        echo '<meta name="project-description" lang="en" content="'.htmlspecialchars(D_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';
    }
    echo '<meta name="publisher" content="'.htmlspecialchars(D_COMPANY_OWNER, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';;
    echo '<meta name="copyright" content="'.htmlspecialchars(D_COMPANY_NAME, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';

?>
    <meta name="author" content="Saurabh Gupta, IT System Developer @ Somex Automation Ltd." />
    <meta name="language" content="english" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-style-type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/css/custom.css"/>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/modernizr.custom.18450.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/cookie.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
        <!-- Google Tag, Hotjar Tag -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$aBgImages = array(
        'signup_bg.png'
);
?>
<div id="header"<?php echo ((!isset($aController[0]) || (strpos($aController[0], '?') !== false)) ? ' class="front" style="background-image: url(gfx/'.getRandomImage($aBgImages).'"' : ''); ?>>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="nav">
            <?php
                echo '<div id="logo-position">';
                    echo '<a href="http://www.somexautomation.ie"> <img src="gfx/logo.png" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 20px;" /></a>';
                    echo '<a href="/" class="button fright"  ">&raquo; Home</a>';
                    echo '</div>';

            ?>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" <?php echo ((!isset($aController[0]) || (strpos($aController[0], '?') !== false)) ? ' class="front"' : ''); ?>>
    <?php
        include ($setPage);
    ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="copyright">
        <span>
            <div="footer-back">
            Phone: +353 (0) 26 65770  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;  Email: automation@somexautomation.ie<br />
            Fax: +353 (0) 26 65780    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &copy;<?php echo date('Y').' '. D_COMPANY_NAME; ?> - Reg No. 584538<br />
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

My `dir_login->index.php` is populated on the `index.php` as a start page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sgupta
 * Date: 28/09/2017
 * Time: 15:46
 */

$pageName = 'dir_login/index.php';
$pageLink = '/';

if (isset($_SESSION['sEmployeeID'])) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $aErrorClass = ' class="text-error"';
    $aError = array();

    if (!isset($_POST['employeeID']) || trim($_POST['employeeID']) == '') {
        $aError['employeeID'] = 'Please type in your Employee ID';
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['password']) || trim($_POST['employeeID'])) {
        $aError['password'] = 'Please type in your password';
    } elseif (!isset($_POST['password']) || (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5)) {
        $aError['password'] = 'This password is wrong';
    }

    if (count($aError) == 0) {
        $sQueryLogin = "
            SELECT employeeID, name, rate, payRate. password, level, email, type
            FROM tblemployees
            WHERE employeeID = ? AND 
                  password = ?
        ";
        if ($stmtLogin = $mysqli->prepare($sQueryLogin)) {
            $sEmployeeID = $_POST['employeeID'];
            $sPassword = $_POST['password'];

            $stmtLogin->bind_param('ss', $sEmployeeID, $sPassword);
            if ($stmtLogin->execute() === false) {
                trigger_error('stmtLogin execution failed '.$stmtLogin->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }
            $stmtLogin->store_result();
            $numLogin = $stmtLogin->num_rows;
            $stmtLogin->bind_result($employeeID, $name, $rate, $payRate, $password, $level, $email, $type);
            $stmtLogin->fetch();

            if ($numLogin == 1) {


            }
        }
    }
}

//echo 'This Page';

?>

<h1>Log in your Somex Timesheets account</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $pageLink; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginForm" class="shadow">
    <?php echo (isset($sLoginError) ? '<h2 class="text-error">'.$sLoginError.'<h2>' : ''); ?>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="employeeID" <?php echo (isset($aError['employeeID'])? $aErrorClass : ''); ?>>Your Employee ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="employeeID" id="employeeID" value="<?php (isset($_POST['employeeID']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['employeeID'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''); ?>" />
            <?php echo (isset($aError['employeeID']) ? '<div class="info-line">'.$aError['employeeID'].'</div>' : ''); ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password"<?php echo (isset($aError['password']) ? $aErrorClass : ''); ?>>Your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <div class="info-line"><?php echo (isset($aError['password']) ? $aError['password'].'<br />' : ''); ?><a href="/forgot-password/">I forgot my password</a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input name="send" type="submit" class="button" value="&raquo; Log in"/>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

The initial page works fine but when I switch to other pages like `forgetpassword.php`or `error.php`, the page gets populated with the code but design is not maintained.

Regardless the undefined links are populating with the design.

The `default` case in the switch statement is working as per I want but not the other pages.

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, label, input, textarea, #nav, .button, #footer, .item, .availability, #place .desc {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #ff6801;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ff1700;
}
.button.fright {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.fright {
    float: right !important;
}
.button.fright {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:  right;
    margin-right: 18%;
    margin-top:60px;
}
#wrapper.front {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

#footer {
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: large;
    background: url(/gfx/signup_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#header {
    background: url(/gfx/signup_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.shadow {
    /*
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    */
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
.text-error, .error {
    color: #e84b31;
}
.text-success, .success {
    color: #2aa00b;
}

input[type="text"]:disabled, select:disabled {
    /*border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    background: transparent;*/
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
input[type="text"]:disabled:hover, select:disabled:hover {
    border: 1px solid #e84b31;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="file"], textarea {
    width: 400px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="file"], textarea, select {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
select {
    padding: 8px 8px 9px !important;
    float: left;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 340px;
    float: left;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label, input[type="radio"] + label {
    float: left;
    width: 450px !important;
    text-align: left;
}
input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover, input[type="file"]:hover, textarea:hover, select:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="file"]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus,
input[type="text"]:active, input[type="password"]:active, input[type="file"]:active, textarea:active, select:active {
    border: 1px solid #00CC66;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
    cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 0 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
form {
    background-color: #f5f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #f1f3f3;
}
form {
    border: 0;
    padding: 30px;
}
.front form {
    width: 920px;
}
.intro {
    margin: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.front form h1 {
    margin: 40px 0 20px !important;
}
form h2 {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.front .column h2 {
    background: #6db7da url(/gfx/arc-small.png) no-repeat center top;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 20px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#search h2 {
    color: #053c71;
}
#search h2, #search h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form ul li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.front form ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.front form ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
form li.header {
    padding: 40px 0 0 340px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    margin: 40px 0 0 !important;
}
form li.header.no-line {
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
form input[type="submit"] {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
form .info-line {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 340px;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.front form .info-line {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h1 + h2, h1 + h3 {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
p {
    line-height: 200%;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
p.warning {
    background-color: #f9f99b;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
ul.warning {
    line-height: 200%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    display: block;
    background-color: #f9f99b;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    list-style: square inside;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
ul.warning li.header {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 16px 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
i {
    font-style: italic;
}
.front p {
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 100px;
}
#wrapper.front {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.front label {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.front form h1 {
    margin: 40px 0 20px !important;
}
form h2 {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
form ul li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.front form ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.front form ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.filter ul {
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #3cb3e7;
}
.filter ul li {
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    display: block;
}
#booking ul {
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #62a903;
}
#booking ul li {
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    display: block;
}
#booking ul li.availability {
    padding-top: 15px;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
}
#booking ul li.dates {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
}
#booking ul li.subtotal-price, .subtotal-price {
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#booking ul li.total-price, .total-price {
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#booking ul li span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
#message-reply ul li {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    display: block;
}
.filter ul li.item {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 140%;
}
form li.header {
    padding: 40px 0 0 340px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    margin: 40px 0 0 !important;
}
form li.header.no-line {
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
form input[type="submit"] {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
form .info-line {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 340px;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.front form .info-line {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Apologies for my English.

Need help
Added Screenshots: [index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1tRu.png), [forgotpassword.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V7Ma.png)

Comment: Why dont you create seperate pages of header.php and footer.php and require them in all the other pages ?

Comment: *apologies for my English* then proceeds to use perfect English. It looks like your styling pages are getting 404ed. Is `forget-password` in a different directory than `index.php?`

Comment: Yes `error.php` and `forgotPassword`is in the same directory `dir_content` as mentioned in the `switch`statement

Comment: Project File Structure : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w1SGcSVMVdckxBelZGTGUwcTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not sure about the design element. As the text in the header and the Footer is populated to all the pages its just the CSS is not populating in other pages.